# no reply messages shown when talking to skype bot from iOS

Tags: skype, botframework

I have a bot that works fine on Skype (windows 10).

On iOS (latest version of skype from app store) I see the bot, I can send him messages but nothing appears when the bot replies. The bot works fine because I see that he processed the message when I switch to Skype on PC.

The bot is in preview. Is there a limitation because of this .... what I have to do to get this working on all clients.

The bot is using BotFramework and processes messages like "item 55".

Comment: Does it work in other skype clients?

Comment: works in skype for windows. did not test on other platforms